# SQL Server: Update where exists and Insert when not exists

Tags: sql-server, merge, exists, not-exists

I have 2 tables, one is called
`INTER` and the other one is called `COM`
The relationship between them is 1:many
Here's the structure of both tables

`INTER`

```
NUMBER
ADDRESS
```

`COM`

```
NUMBER
CONTACT
REFERENCE
```

To give some context about the tables:

The `ADDRESS` field from the `INTER` table can be *empty* (empty string '')

The `CONTACT` field of the `COM` table can be of two types: *"E-mail" or "Website"*

What I'm trying to accomplish is the following:

I want to look at all the records from `COM` where `CONTACT`=*'Website'* and insert into `COM` the values of `(INTER.NUMBER,'Website',INTER.ADDRESS)`
where `INTER.ADDRESS`<>'' and `INTER.NUMBER` *does not exist* in `COM.NUMBER`

Otherwise, I want to update the value of `COM.REFERENCE`, set it to `INTER.ADDRESS` where `COM.CONTACT`=*'Website'* and `INTER.NUMBER` exists in `COM.NUMBER` and `INTER.ADDRESS`<>''

How can I accomplish this? I know what the merge statement is but according to the documentation merge does not work well on filtered queries. Also, I know about the exists statement but I don't know how to make this query work.

In case you're wondering, unfortunately, the structure of these tables cannot be modified.

Some sample data:

`INTER`

```
ABCD123,google.com
XUEH342,facebook.com
IISI521,twitter.com
IEIEK885,''
```

`COM`

```
ABCD123, Website, test.com
ABCD123,E-mail,bob@gmail.com
XUEH342,Website,facebook.com
XASE456,Website, stackoverflow.com
XASE456,E-mail,tom@gmail.com
```

After running the query, the results on COM table would look as the following:

```
ABCD123,Website, google.com
ABCD123,E-mail,bob@gmail.com
XUEH342,Website, facebook.com
IISI521,Website, twitter.com
XASE456,Website, stackoverflow.com
XASE456,E-mail,tom@gmail.com
```

As you can see, IISI521,twitter.com got inserted,ABCD123,test.com got updated and IEIEK885,'' didn't get inserted because is an empty string.

Comment: Sample data, and expected results, will help us help you., along with *your* attempts.

Comment: Sure, let me update the question

Answer (score 1):

```
    You can try below query:
        
    MERGE com with (HOLDLOCK) AS cm
USING (SELECT a.number, a.address, b.contact FROM inter a left join com b on a.number = b.number and b.contact = 'website'  WHERE a.address != '' ) AS intr
ON cm.number = intr.number and cm.contact = intr.contact
WHEN MATCHED  THEN
    UPDATE
            SET     cm.reference = intr.address
                    
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT
      (
            number,
            contact,
            reference
      )
    VALUES
      (
            intr.number,
            'website',
            intr.address
      );
```

Comment: Hello @Pareshk, according to the MERGE documentation There is a caution on the on statement:
 Caution
It's important to specify only the columns from the target table to use for matching purposes. That is, specify columns from the target table that are compared to the corresponding column of the source table. Don't attempt to improve query performance by filtering out rows in the target table in the ON clause; for example, such as specifying AND NOT target_table.column_x = value. Doing so may return unexpected and incorrect results.
Will this still work?

Comment: Here's the link of the MERGE documentation. [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: @PedroEmilioVélez, yes you are right. My bad. But there is work around solution which can give you your desired output by modifying the derived table used in USING clause. I have edited my my answer.